# Print file in PHP 5.6 (still) not possible?

Tags: php, printing

I am using **PHP 5.6** and to print something, I have to edit ***php.ini*** and include the ***php_printer.dll*** file. But there is no ***.dll fiile*** for PHP 5.6.

What I am trying to solve:

I want to connect the voucher-printer to the server/webpage. When a customer orders products, the order will be printed automaticly on the voucher-printer.

Are there other solutions? I have read, that some printers/voucher-printers can get E-Mails.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the name of the Extension you are using and for what exact PHP Version? PHP version must contain this information: x86 or x64, TS or NonTS, Version of VC compiler. You can get all of this from the output of the function `phpinfo()` or from the cmd `php -i`

Comment: I wanted to use the "php_printer.dll" extension for PHP 5.6. But it seems to be not compatible with PHP 5.6. My version: x86 and TS. But I didn't find the version of VC compiler.

Comment: Please check the output of phpinfo() of your old and running PHP instance and show the Block about your printer extension.

Answer (score 4):

I also was looking for the same hope you have solved it.

But there are no answer, so here is the link where I found php_printer.dll for PHP 5.6, and it worked for me.

https://github.com/gimjudge/php

Comment: Meanwhile, I solved it on other way. But I didn't find any solution for that. I will definately test your solution, maybe I'll need it later :-)

Comment: okay bro, actually I had the same issue today and came along your question then found that dll so just posted for other people.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11937838)

Comment: @BhumiShah but question requests the php_printer.dll file for PHP 5.6.

Comment: @MuratYazi I have the same problem actually and looking for how to include the extension. How did you solve your issue ?

Comment: @pollux1er I generated an E-Mail. I am using the auto print addin (filtaquilla 1.3.1) for thunderbird. So incoming E-Mails on the main PC are automatically printed.

Comment: @mokNathal, could you please tell how you solved it. I have wampserver with PHP 5.6.25 and tried to install it. But it fails with error: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_printer.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` I then installed PHP 5.6.8 as mentioned in the dll file itself. It loads the extension without error, but when I try to execute the printer_open() command in the browser, it fails with fatal error: `Call to undefined function printer_open()'. I am having a hard time and would love to get some suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Many PECL extensions can be found on this site, but you need to match PHP version, platform and compiler of the extension to your PHP file.

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/

It seems there was a "printer" extension on PECL a very long time ago. You may find windows versions of it somewhere, but most likely this extensian is dead.

http://pecl.php.net/package/printer

The top three lines of phpinfo() contain your version information. A small sample from my instance:

- System: **Windows** NT 6.2 build 9200 (Windows 8.1 Home Premium Edition) i586
- Build Date: Jul 23 2014 14:58:09
- Compiler: **MSVC11** (Visual C++ 2012)
- Architecture: **x86**